# Custom home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to make home page of WordPress to show my custom index.html page instead of default without creating page in WordPress and left the rest post page remain unchanged.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? Which theme?

Comment: @AhmedGinani I'm using default theme provided by the WordPress. And what I'm trying to do is when any user visit my website with my domain name like at home page [link](http://example.com)[/link] then I will show them my custom home template design by me and when the user visit my website with post url then show them default post template of wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show your index.html as homepage by modifying index.php file.

Just use ,

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
  // your index.html code
}
else{
 // default index.php code
}
```

I assume you are using twnetyseventeen theme.

Comment: Not working showing this error
http://example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I'm doing this
` if(is_home() || is_front_page()){

        readfile("index.html");

} else {

        define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

        /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

}`

Comment: index.html must inside the root of the folder.

Comment: Yes it's is in same folder as of index.php

Comment: ok and you are changing index.php of root folder or of theme folder?

Comment: Sorry Now I get it Thanks :)